# How to use the ibm_boto3 in python

Tags: ibm-cloud, object-storage

**Who has the same problem?**

I want to store data in **cos**, but cannot use the **ibm_boto3** on my machine.
To be sure to check with a sample, I used the code from the sample from this [ibm-cos-sdk](https://github.com/IBM/ibm-cos-sdk-python) github.

Installed

```
pip3 freeze
backports.functools-lru-cache==1.5
botocore==1.12.28
docutils==0.14
futures==3.1.1
ibm-cos-sdk==2.3.2
ibm-cos-sdk-core==2.3.2
ibm-cos-sdk-s3transfer==2.3.2
-e git://github.com/boto/jmespath.git@1c9c35cf681b6605d8629e5ce8865221a4fd2a30#egg=jmespath
mock==1.3.0
nose==1.3.3
pbr==5.0.0
python-dateutil==2.7.3
s3transfer==0.1.13
six==1.11.0
urllib3==1.23
```

Here is my cli result and as you can see the **ibm_boto3** is not found.

```
python3 test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
   import ibm_boto3
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibm_boto3/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
   from ibm_boto3.session import Session
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibm_boto3/session.py", line 27, in <module>
   import ibm_botocore.session
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibm_botocore/session.py", line 37, in <module>
   import ibm_botocore.credentials
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibm_botocore/credentials.py", line 36, in <module>
   import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Comment: This looks like it might be a defect in the latest release.  Which version are you using?

Comment: As you can see in the freeze: 
ibm-cos-sdk==2.3.2
ibm-cos-sdk-core==2.3.2
ibm-cos-sdk-s3transfer==2.3.2

Comment: I apparently hadn't had my coffee.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, it looks like `requests` somehow fell out of the requirements file in the latest release.  The team is patching it and will release an update soon.

In the meantime, you can manually install the package in your environment with `pip3 install requests` or by manually adding it to the `requirements.txt` file:

`echo "requests==2.18.0" >> path/to/requirements.txt`